# Could not install CocoaPods in OSX 10.11

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

## Error Show on Terminal

SSMAC100s-Mac:~ ssmac100$ sudo gem install cocoa pods

Password:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/cocoapods-1.0.0.gemspec.rz)

Comment: correct command is `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this its worked for me.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```